# How to Make Glass Less Reflective?

Tags: glass

So I am making my first interior scene and I have made a coffee table but am struggling to make it less reflective. It looks as though it's a mirror and I just want to know how can I make it more transparent.[image]

Comment: Try turning down the IOR by a small amount (1.150 seems right)

Comment: What exactly does the IOR stand for and what does it control?

Comment: @Akados It stands for Index Of Refraction and it is a measure of how a transparent material behaves and interacts with light in the physical world. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index

Answer (score 8):

I believe you've most likely got your Normals flipped the wrong way. This makes the surface behave like the *inside* of the glass and results in an effect called Total Internal Reflection when hit by light at a shallow angle - ie, it effectively acts as a glossy surface.

The solution is to edit the glass mesh (select it and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into Edit mode), select all (<kbd>A</kbd> until the whole mesh is selected), then go to Mesh/Normals/Flip Normals - or press <kbd>Space</kbd> and type 'Flip Normals'. Once done, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to come out of Edit mode. Your glass should now behave as it should.

To demonstrate this, here's an example scene consisting of a cube sitting above a plane with a Glass shader material, with a further plane below and a large doughnut above. With the correct normal this produces the following result :

[image: normal glass]

Note the subtle reflection in the glass as you would expect.

Flipping the normal (so it now points down) produces the following result :

[image: bad normal glass]

ie, it acts as a mirror. This is a result of the Total Internal Reflection due to the rays acting as if they are hitting a surface on the inside of a block of glass.

---

Note that a similar effect to swapping the normals can be achieved by using an IOR of less than 1.0. ie, changing the IOR to 1/1.45 = 0.69 would produce the 'correct' result, without flipping the normals as the glass would then behave as its inverse; instead of being a 'block' of glass surrounded by air it would behave as a cavity of air within a block of glass (ie, as if its normals were pointed the ‘wrong’ way).

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer Rich! Really helped :)